# The computer is lagging when the lid is closed (probably caused by the dedicated gpu)

Tags: xorg

I have a problem with my laptop MSI Bravo 15. I know that Wayland solves the problem, but I want to use the global buttons in applications like Discord and that's why I want to use X window manager. Cinnamon DE with software rendering also works fine, but it burns my CPU. I can't change the graphics card through system76-power, because it sees only integrated card.

Graphics cards listed below:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x54 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:Unknown AMD Radeon GPU @ pci:0000:08:00.0
Provider 1: id: 0x84 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 5 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:Radeon RX 5500M @ pci:0000:03:00.0
```

The OS which I am using right now:

```
$ screenfetch
                            
                             OS: Pop 21.10 impish
                             Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.22-xanmod1
         #####               Uptime: 27m
        #######              Packages: 0
        ##O#O##              Shell: bash 5.1.8
        #######              Resolution: 1920x1080
      ###########            DE: Cinnamon 4.8.6
     #############           WM: Muffin
    ###############          WM Theme:  (Default)
    ################         GTK Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
   #################         Icon Theme: gnome
 #####################       Font: Sans 9
 #####################       Disk: 20G / 330G (7%)
   #################         CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics @ 12x 3GHz
                             GPU: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.1, 256 bits)
                             RAM: 2660MiB / 15402MiB
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev c1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] (rev c1)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 501a
07:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN550 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7)
08:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
08:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
08:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
08:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
08:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
09:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
09:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have solved the problem. If you want to resolve the problem, then just go to

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf
```

and write this

```
Section "Device"

Identifier "Vega"

Driver "amdgpu"

BusID "PCI:8:0:0"

EndSection


Section "Device"

Identifier "Navi"

Driver "amdgpu"

BusID "PCI:3:0:0"

EndSection


#Section "Screen"

# Identifier "VegaScreen"

# Device "Vega"

#EndSection


Section "Screen"

Identifier "NaviScreen"

Device "Navi"

EndSection
```

It works fine with my laptop.

Comment: Could you please explain this code a little bit?